# Nginx ldap require group

Tags: nginx, ldap

I have compiled and configured nginx to work with ldap and our ActiveDirectory. All works with this configuration:

```
ldap_server MyAD {
   url ldap://100.100.100.11:3268/DC=<mydomain>,DC=<myext>?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=user);
    binddn "<user>";
    binddn_passwd <password>;
    group_attribute member;
    group_attribute_is_dn on;
    require valid_user;
  }
```

My site require authentication and only users in ActiveDirectory can access.
Now I'm trying to allow only users that are in a specific ActiveDirectory group, but with no success, can anyone help me to fix the url query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

`url ldap://100.100.100.11:3268/DC=<mydomain>,DC=<myext>?sAMAccountName?sub?(&(objectClass=user)(memberOf=<DN OF THE GROUP>));`

The filter search for entries which are at the same time :

- of the `user` type
- member of the group defined by the entry `<DN OF THE GROUP>`

Comment: @xergiopd What configuration did you use?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `require valid_user`, you can add `require group "dn_of_the_group"`.